# Show more of div's content text when inner button or the div itself is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code and I wonder if I can show the rest of text when clicking on the div area instead of only the button and if its possible to connect them together.

```js
function ReadMore(event) {
  var dots = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".dots");
  var moreText = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".more");
  var btnText = event.target;

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.more { 
  display: none; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="glide__slide">
    <h3>Inka B.</h3>
    <p>Nádherné místo u lesa, ubytování v krásných, čistých zrenovovaných prostorách. Společná kuchyň velká se 3 linkami, 2 sporáky, 2 mikrovlnkami... když je více lidí, stále se dá vařit. A vedlejší jídelna pojme přes 20 lidí
        <span class="dots">...</span>
        <span class="more">- ideální i na rodinnou oslavu. Postele pohodlné, pokoje útulné...a ten výhled z terasy! Na
            všem se dalo domluvit...zkrátka, vracíme se zpět! Cítili jsme se tu opravdu vítání. Děkujeme!</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="ReadMore(event)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to only have the event listener on the parent. And to change your query selectors so you use the `event.currentTarget` instead of the `event.target`, so it behaves identically no matter where the event is coming from in the `div`.

```js
function ReadMore(event) {
  var dots = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".dots");
  var moreText = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".more");
  var btnText = event.currentTarget.querySelector("button");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="glide__slide" onclick="ReadMore(event)">
  <h3>Inka B.</h3>
  <p>Nádherné místo u lesa, ubytování v krásných, čistých
    zrenovovaných prostorách. Společná kuchyň velká se 3 linkami,
    2 sporáky, 2 mikrovlnkami... když je více lidí, stále se dá vařit.
    A vedlejší jídelna pojme přes 20 lidí
    <span class="dots">...</span>
    <span class="more">- ideální i na rodinnou oslavu. Postele pohodlné, pokoje útulné...a ten výhled z terasy! Na všem se dalo domluvit...zkrátka, vracíme se zpět! Cítili jsme se tu opravdu vítání. Děkujeme!</span>
  </p>
  <button class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yes and it avoids the whole discussion about the event bubbling. It's actually a better option indeed

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Yes. But remember the problem on this approach  would be come  if you have multiple div boxes. If you only have one `glide__slide` then is everthing okay. but if you have more then would be better to use the event.target container

Comment: @MaikLowrey you make a point, I edited my answer. He just should use `event.currentTarget`. As you did below @MaikLowrey in your answer, you would get an error if the event is triggered by the hidden `span` for example.

Comment: my answer was buggy and I didn't realize before... I corrected the problem. Anyway I still think it was much easier to stick with the event handler on parent only at that point.. having it shared just adds some more scalability in terms of change but it's pointless. Things are supposed to require efforts when those efforts are needed.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I was talking about the answer of MaikLowrey. I didn't realise that yours was buggy. And thanks for the approval of my approach :)

Comment: Yes your are right and thanks for the hint to use currentTarget to avoid error if somebody click on the span. i learned something .... merci and +1up for this good hint.

Comment: *Content d'avoir pu être utile et merci à vous @MaikLowrey:)* I'm gonna delete soon that comment or I'm gonna be in trouble if some moderator passes by.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here was using `event.stopPropagation()` when the event was fired by the button. That's because the event will bubble to the parent when the button gets clicked (because both the element have the handlers registered for that event) and it would trigger the handler twice otherwise.

I'll be more clear. You have both the div container and the button listening to the click event. If the click occurs on the button, it will first cause the handler listening for the button to trigger. After that, since the button is nested inside the div and that div has an handler listening for the click event, also that one will be triggered (because the event is said to bubble up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture). To avoid the handler to be called twice for the same event, I'm checking if the element firing the event is the button and in that case it will stop the propagation (the bubbling up to the parent).

```js
function ReadMore(event) {    

    //this is a brutal way to get the html elements based on which element fired the event
    if(event.target.classList.contains('myBtn')){      
      btn = event.currentTarget;
      dots = btn.parentElement.querySelector('.dots');
      more = btn.parentElement.querySelector('.more');      
    }else{    
      btn = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.myBtn');
      dots = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.dots');
      more = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.more');      
    }
    
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
      more.style.display = "none";
    } else {          
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
      more.style.display = "inline";
    }
    
    if(event.target.classList.contains('myBtn'))
      window.event.stopPropagation();
    
  }
```

```css
button.myBtn{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="glide__slide" onclick="ReadMore(event)">
  <h3>Inka B.</h3>
  <p>Nádherné místo u lesa, ubytování v krásných, čistých 
      zrenovovaných prostorách. Společná kuchyň velká se 3 linkami, 
      2 sporáky, 2 mikrovlnkami... když je více lidí, stále se dá vařit. 
      A vedlejší jídelna pojme přes 20 lidí
      <span class="dots">...</span>
      <span class="more" style="display:none;">- ideální i na rodinnou oslavu. Postele pohodlné, pokoje útulné...a ten výhled z terasy! Na všem se dalo domluvit...zkrátka, vracíme se zpět! Cítili jsme se tu opravdu vítání. Děkujeme!
      </span>
  </p>
  <button onclick="ReadMore(event)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**update** use currentTarget and assign the click event on the entire div. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

My first answer i recommended to use `parentNode` to fetch the div.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode . But this will trough a error if you will click on the hidden span. Thanks to @YoussoufOumar. He pointed out ;-)

```js
function ReadMore(event) {  
  const div = event.currentTarget; 
  var dots = div.querySelector(".dots");  
  var moreText = div.querySelector(".more");
  var btnText = div.querySelector("button");
    
  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
  }
```

```css
.more {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="glide__slide" onclick="ReadMore(event)">
  <h3>Inka B.</h3>
  <p>Nádherné místo u lesa, ubytování v krásných, čistých 
    zrenovovaných prostorách. Společná kuchyň velká se 3 linkami, 
    2 sporáky, 2 mikrovlnkami... když je více lidí, stále se dá vařit. 
    A vedlejší jídelna pojme přes 20 lidí
    <span class="dots">...</span>
    <span class="more">- ideální i na rodinnou oslavu. Postele pohodlné, pokoje útulné...a ten výhled z terasy! Na všem se dalo domluvit...zkrátka, vracíme se zpět! Cítili jsme se tu opravdu vítání. Děkujeme!</span></p>
  <button class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```